# How to fix PowerShell 7.3.0 Fatal error 0xC0000005

Tags: powershell, windows-11

[Installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/scripting/whats-new/migrating-from-windows-powershell-51-to-powershell-7?view=powershell-7.3#installing-powershell-7) PowerShell 7.3.0 on Windows 11 using the [MSI package](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.3.0/PowerShell-7.3.0-win-x86.msi). All seemed good. But I get an error when I try running it using either of these two methods:

1. On Terminal, select *Powershell* in *Open a new tab*
2. Under Command Prompt, type `pwsh`.

The error is the same:

```
>pwsh
PowerShell 7.3.0
Fatal error. 0xC0000005
   at System.Management.Automation.Security.SystemPolicy+WldpNativeMethods.WldpCanExecuteFile(System.Guid, WLDP_EXECUTION_EVALUATION_OPTIONS, IntPtr, System.String, WLDP_EXECUTION_POLICY ByRef)
...
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
```

There is a post on GitHub that describes [an identical issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18545). But my understanding of their proposed solution is to use version 7.2.7 instead. Before I go figure out how to do that, would appreciate knowing if anyone has an actual solution or a better suggestion. Otherwise, I can post an answer later to report if an earlier version (or an alternative) works.

Comment: In order to rule out the simplest solution. Download the version contained within a .zip file (64-bit version obviously), and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Thanks. The GitHub issue talks about the zip file, so would expect the same result...

Comment: Can you confirm?  I can confirm the zip file works on Windows 10.  If the file does not work on Windows 10, using a previous version, seems like the only solution you have until a new (fixed) version can be released.

Comment: The post indicates that with Powershell 7.3.0 that this is a bug when running PowerShell 7.3.0 x86 package on a Windows 11 x64 system. The fix per this bug is to run the x64 bit packages of PowerShell 7.3.0 on your Windows 11 x64 OS until you hear that this bug is fixed in a newer release than PowerShell 7.3.0. Some also stated this is not an issue with PowerShell 7.2.7 so downgrading to an older PowerShell version without the bug may be another workaround until it's patched in a newer release. Read the post thoroughly for technical detail but that's what is it saying basically.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I should have installed the [win-x64](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.3.0/PowerShell-7.3.0-win-x64.msi) package, don't know what I was thinking! Uninstalled the x86 and installed with the x64 MSI and it works fine! Thank you! Should I delete this question, or do you want to post an answer to help others who might make the same mistake?

Comment: I see that I had actually linked the correct MSI in the original question, but looking at my downloads folder, that's not I had previously. Will update the question to show the *incorrect* file I mistakenly used.

Comment: @Ramhound this is now sorted when I used the x64 MSI package. Safe to say that it would probably also work with x64 ZIP file, which I'm guessing is the one you used. And also concluding that the same issue would exist had I used the x86 zip file. Was a long day, didn't realize I was using the wrong installation file. Sorry for the unnecessary question and thanks for the help.

Comment: @Nagev - Yes, I tried the x64 package, contained within the archive.  I didn't even think to try the x86 package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced post indicates with PowerShell 7.3.0 *this is a bug when running PowerShell 7.3.0 x86 package on a Windows 11 x64 system*.

**The fix per this bug is to run the x64 bit package of PowerShell 7.3.0** on your Windows 11 x64 OS until the bug is fixed in a newer release than PowerShell 7.3.0.

Others state this is not an issue with PowerShell 7.2.7 so **downgrading to an older PowerShell version without the bug is another workaround** until it's patched in a newer release.

Read the post thoroughly for technical detail but that's what is it saying basically.

> ### [7.3.0 x86 crashes on startup on Windows 11 22H2](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18545)
>
> **`rhubarb-geek-nz` commented**
>
> I just tried the 7.3.0 x86 zip on my Windows 11 Pro 22H2 and that
> throws exactly the same exception as you describe.
>
> **`chrullrich` commented**
>
> Yes, 7.2.7 works. It does not contain this particular bug anyway, that
> was introduced between v7.3.0-preview.3 and .4 according to git.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [PowerShell on the Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MZ1SNWT0N5D), which at the time of answering, shows Version 7.3.0. Have not tried it yet, to avoid conflicts with my current installation, but might be an option for some, and hopefully it would install correctly.